# How to find corresponding assembly for c++ code

Tags: c++, assembly

I have a rather long function containing a loop which I want to optimize. When I compile the code using `gcc -S -O3` i get some thousand lines of assembly. How do I find the corresponding assembly code for the loop I am interested in ?

Comment: Stop in the debugger and see disassembly window.

Comment: Also, compile using `g++ -S -fverbose-asm` (perhaps adding also `-O`)

Comment: Be careful when trying to optimize the assembly directly. The compiler might have done a few tricks in other places of the code. It's better to try using the right settings, and use intrinsics instead.

Comment: I've forgotten to mention that I turned on optimisation by `-O3`.

Comment: @Tintin I am not intending to optimize the assembly directly, I would like to check if the compiler did optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be best to use a debugger, such as ddd and look at the corresponding assembly code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set a breakpoint, run your code and you'll see the disassembly with all the symbols corresponding to your code.